# unable to get the ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I am new to symfony. I have created a twig file named as `index.html.twig`. In this I have written a code for making an ajax request as follow:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function onsub()
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('source').value);
        var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var name="rohit";
        if(http.open("POST", "sub.html.php?field="+name, true)) alert('yes');
        alert(http);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
            {

                alert('i m back');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('sorry');
            }
        }  

        http.send();
    }

    </script>
```

This is the action called when I press the submit button to submit a form. when I submit the form, this action is called and the correct value is poped out but it is not sending the data to requested file i.e. `sub.html.php`. it is making the object correctly. and when I am printing the value of `http.readyState` then it is giving the answer as `1`. so I want to send the value of `name` to the requested file `sub.html.php`. what can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this .....

```
<script language="javascript">
function onsub() 
{ 
   var name="rohit";
   alert(document.getElementById('source').value); 
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
   { 
      http=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } 
   else 
   { 
    // code    for IE6, IE5 
    http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
   }
   http.onreadystatechange=function() 
   { 
     if(http.readyState == 4 &&    http.status == 200) 
     { 
       alert('i m back'); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
       alert('sorry'); 
     }
   }    
   http.open("GET", "sub.php?field="+name , true); 
   http.send(); 
   }    
   </script>
```

Comment: I have tried this but I am not getting the answer. When I am taking the answer of http.readyState then it is 0